# How to execute SSIS package from SQL Server stored procedure and pass arguments

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, etl

I'm trying to execute a SSIS package via a stored procedure.

I'm able to successfully execute that stored procedure only when the parameters are hard coded (like described in the first version of the code)

First version of the code:

```
SELECT @Cmd = 'DTexec /F "C:\ssis\tool\package1.dtsx" 
                      /SET "\Package.Variables[User::ConfigurationName].Properties[Value]";"Report1" 
                      /SET "\Package.Variables[User::Country].Properties[Value]";"USA" 
                      /SET "\Package.Variables[User::OrgDepartment_Team].Properties[Value]";"USA" 
                      /SET "\Package.Variables[User::Subfix].Properties[Value]";"20190503" 
                      /SET "\Package.Variables[User::TeamName].Properties[Value]";"Team1"'
```

A record is created in database

But the code below does not work (I'm passing the same parameter values)

Second version of the code:

```
SELECT @Cmd = 'DTexec /F "C:\ssis\tool\package1.dtsx" 
                      /SET "\Package.Variables[User::ConfigurationName].Properties[Value]";"' + @ConfigurationName + 
                   '" /SET "\Package.Variables[User::Country].Properties[Value]";"' + @Country + 
                   '" /SET "\Package.Variables[User::OrgDepartment_Team].Properties[Value]";"' + @OrgDepartment_Team +
                   '" /SET "\Package.Variables[User::Subfix].Properties[Value]";"' + @Subfix + 
                   '" /SET "\Package.Variables[User::TeamName].Properties[Value]";"' + @TeamName + '"'
```

There is no error but there is also no record created in the database.

> DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: You can try adding  ` /rep iwr` to the end of the invocation and look at the logging information generated. Also, do an explicit print or log the generated command value into a table with your hard coded versus dynamic version. I suspect you'll see what's "bad" in the supplied values

Comment: @billinkc the syntax looks ok, but the issue may be caused by *nulls* or *quotes*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Trying to figure out the issue

It looks like you are using a working syntax, but i will provide some suggestion that may helps to solve the issue:

### (1) NULL handling

Check that none of the variable used in the command contains NULL values which may cause that the concatenated string value will be `NULL`, you can use `ISNULL()` to solve the issue.

```
SELECT @ConfigurationName = ISNULL(@ConfigurationName,'') , 
       @Country = ISNULL(@Country ,'') ,
       @OrgDepartment_Team = ISNULL(@OrgDepartment_Team,'') ,
       @Subfix  = ISNULL(@Subfix ,'') ,
       @TeamName = ISNULL(@TeamName,'')
```

### (2) Quotes Handling

I prefer that quotes are included within the variables instead of the main string. You can use `QUOTENAME()` function to achieve that:

```
SELECT @ConfigurationName = QUOTENAME(ISNULL(@ConfigurationName,''),'"') , 
       @Country = QUOTENAME(ISNULL(@Country ,''),'"') ,
       @OrgDepartment_Team = QUOTENAME(ISNULL(@OrgDepartment_Team,''),'"') ,
       @Subfix  = QUOTENAME(ISNULL(@Subfix ,''),'"') ,
       @TeamName = QUOTENAME(ISNULL(@TeamName,''),'"')

SELECT @Cmd = 'DTexec /F "C:\ssis\tool\package1.dtsx" 
                      /SET "\Package.Variables[User::ConfigurationName].Properties[Value]";' + @ConfigurationName + 
                   ' /SET "\Package.Variables[User::Country].Properties[Value]";' + @Country + 
                   ' /SET "\Package.Variables[User::OrgDepartment_Team].Properties[Value]";' + @OrgDepartment_Team +
                   ' /SET "\Package.Variables[User::Subfix].Properties[Value]";' + @Subfix + 
                   ' /SET "\Package.Variables[User::TeamName].Properties[Value]";' + @TeamName
```

### (3) Reporting

You can read the entire package log by adding `/Rep EWIP` keyword to the command:

```
SELECT @Cmd = 'DTexec /F "C:\ssis\tool\package1.dtsx" /Rep EWIP '
```

> /Rep[orting] level [;event_guid_or_name[;event_guid_or_name[...]]: (Optional). Specifies what types of messages to report. The available reporting options for level are as follows:
>
> N No reporting.
>
> E Errors are reported.
>
> W Warnings are reported.
>
> I Informational messages are reported.
>
> C Custom events are reported.
>
> D Data Flow task events are reported.
>
> P Progress is reported.
>
> V Verbose reporting

**References**

- [dtexec - Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2017#parameter)